# Jquery Fullcalendar - Show event details in dialog overlay

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to display the event details when clicked in a dialog modal window (like the google calendar).  I was able to get the jquery qtips script to display on mouseover, but can not figure out how to get the event to display in a modal overlay.  I know qtips has an overlay, but how to place the call within fullcalendar I am getting lost doing.  Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/) callback you can handle clicks on events in the calendar and then open a dialog with details. I don't know qtip but [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) provides nice functionality to show dialogs, also modal ones.